# PHP AJAX image upload - I need to limit quota to a folder

Tags: php, ajax, upload, limit, filesize

I am using Ajax PHP to upload images to a folder, but I want to limit that space to 50 MB. I think I'm on the right track, but the code does not work for me. If you can help me.

I think the error should be in "if ($ size> 52428800) {"

Thank you

```
/*** Calling from ajax to add the gallery new an image****/
 public function Addgallery() {
            $size = 0;
            $files= glob($directory.$folder_gallery.'/*');
            foreach($files as $path){
                is_file($path) && $size += filesize($path);
                is_dir($path) && get_dir_size($path);
            }
            return $size;
    if ($size > 52428800 ) {
        echo alert("Your quota on disk does not allow the upload of images. Please erase images that you do not use.");
    } else {
        $this->_upload_file($this->_base_path .'/images/gallery/', array( '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif' ), 'addgallery');

    }

}
```

Comment: What's this syntax? `is_file($path) && $size += filesize($path);` strike that I know what it does I just dont like it, I prefer `$size = is_file($path) ? $size + filesize($path) : $size;` -- just saying.  Or just a one line if, just looks like a typo to me, but I am old school I guess

Comment: That said, if each "user" had his own folder could you not just get the total size of that folder?

Comment: Yes, I define the folder user with  `$directory.$folder_gallery.`
It is defined within the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `$size` on line 9. Everything below the return statement will be skipped.

If you move `return $size` below the else, your code should work.

```
/*** Calling from ajax to add the gallery new an image****/
public function Addgallery() {
    $size = 0;
    $files = glob($directory.$folder_gallery.'/*');
    foreach($files as $path){
        is_file($path) && $size += filesize($path);
        is_dir($path) && get_dir_size($path);
    }
    if ($size > 52428800){
        echo alert("Your quota on disk does not allow the upload of images. Please erase images that you do not use.");
    } else {
        $this->_upload_file($this->_base_path .'/images/gallery/', array( '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif' ), 'addgallery');
    }
    return $size;
}
```

*Note: `alert()` is not a PHP function, just in case you didn't create that function*